# Linking a command to a chat using NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver, nltk

I am building a simple chatbot and want it to run a command when a specific question/answer is given.

for example: 
Chatbot: "What can I do for you today?" 
User: "Open google" 
Chatbot: "Opening www.google.com"
Chatbot runs command = WebDriver.open('www.google.com')

Current code for testing: (TKinter only used for testing please ignore tkinter code)

```
import nltk
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = TK()

root.geometry(100x100+100+100)
root.title("Chatbot")

pairs = [

["Hi im (.*)",["hello %1, What can I do for you?"]],
["Open google",["opening www.google.com"]],+OpenG() ##### this is where I need help as concatenating commands does not work

]

def firstChatBot():
    print("Greetings! My name is Chatbot-T1, What is yours?.")
    Chatbot = Chat(pairs, reflections)
    Chatbot.converse()

def openG():
    print("Opening www.google.com")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.googe.com")

btn1 = Button(root, text="Chat", command=firstChatBot).grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: to open page in webbrowser you can use standard module `webbrowser` and `webbrowser.open("https://www.googe.com")` - it will use default web browser to open this url. If you use filename instead of url then it should try to use default program for its extension - ie. for `.txt` it will use default editor.

Comment: there is [source code for Chat](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html) and it doesn't have method to run functions. You would have to use this code and change `response to get three elemens `(pattern, response, function_name)` instead of `(pattern, response)` and run `function_name()`. And then you can use `["Open google",["opening www.google.com"], openG]`. Ther should be `openG` without `()` and other question should also ie. `None` as third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [source code for class Chat in nltk](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html) and it doesn't have method to run functions.

You would have to use this code and change method `response` (and `__init__`) to get three elemens `(pattern, response, function_name)` instead of `(pattern, response)` and run `function_name()`.

And then you can use

```
["Open google", ["opening www.google.com"], open_google]
```

There should be `open_google` without `()` and other question should have `None` as third element.

**EDIT:** I addded `match` to `callback()` so now function question and al matches in `(.*)` and it can check what was in question.

I used `Open (.*)` so callback can check what was in `(.*)` and run different pages.  If you write `Open google` then it open `www.gooogle.com`, if you write `Open so` then it opens `www.StackOverflow.com`

```
import nltk
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import re
import random
import webbrowser

class MyChat(Chat):

    def __init__(self, pairs, reflections={}):

        # add `z` because now items in pairs have three elements
        self._pairs = [(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE), y, z) for (x, y, z) in pairs]
        self._reflections = reflections
        self._regex = self._compile_reflections()

    def respond(self, str):

        # add `callback` because now items in pairs have three elements
        for (pattern, response, callback) in self._pairs:
            match = pattern.match(str)

            if match:

                resp = random.choice(response)
                resp = self._wildcards(resp, match)

                if resp[-2:] == '?.':
                    resp = resp[:-2] + '.'
                if resp[-2:] == '??':
                    resp = resp[:-2] + '?'

                # run `callback` if exists  
                if callback: # eventually: if callable(callback):
                    callback(match)

                return resp

# --- create function before `pairs` ---

#def open_google(match):
#    webbrowser.open('https://google.com')

def open_something(match):
    #webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
    groups = match.groups()
    if groups:
        if groups[0] == 'google':
            webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
        elif groups[0] == 'so':
            webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
        else:
            print('What is "{}"?'.format(groups[0]))
    else:
        print("I don't know what to open")

# --- every question needs `callback` or `None`---

pairs = [
    ["Hi im (.*)", ["hello %1, What can I do for you?"], None],
#    ["Open google", ["opening www.google.com"], open_google],
    ["Open (.*)", ["opening something ..."], open_something],
]

print("Greetings! My name is Chatbot-T1, What is yours?.")
Chatbot = MyChat(pairs, reflections)
Chatbot.converse()
```

Comment: I added `match` in `callback()`

Comment: Hi @furas thanks so much for the help! :D I'll play around with your example.

Comment: Just wondering, why those `??` `?.`  Replacements?

Comment: Its kinda weird since it opens something 1st then prints opening something. Like callback first then response. Is there any other way round?

Comment: @RatulHasan in answer is link to [source code for class Chat in nltk](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html) and there is code with comments - and there is comment which explains `??` `?.` - `"# fix munged punctuation at the end`

Comment: @RatulHasan in the same link you can see how works function `converse()` - it runs `response()` to get text response and display it. But in `response()` I added function to run code which open function. You can print text before executing `callback()` but next you would have to change `converse()` to skip this text after running `response()` - so it would need more work.